# $_FILES empty after AJAX upload

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm developing a simple script to upload a file through AJAX but after form submission, the variable $_FILES is completely empty, although the file exists within php://input, but with no simple way to extract only the file. Anyone knows the reason and/or solution to this problem?

I've checked all the common solutions.
enctype="multipart/form-data"
rights to temp folder
form-tags closing
doublequotations
and the output of the file-input in JS

Nothing has solved my problem.

**RED**
This is NOT jquery, and I haven't found a duplicate in 24h. So please don't mark as duplicate unless you're sure it is one.

**HTML**

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="testf">
<input type="file" name="file" accept=".jpg">
<input type="submit" value="Skicka">
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
let data = document.querySelector("#testf");
data.onsubmit = function() {
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open("upload.php", data.action);
    http.onreadystatechange = function () {
        console.log(http.response);
    }
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", data.enctype);
    http.send(new FormData(data));
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
var_dump($_FILES);
?>
```

This should print the contents of my file, but

```
array(0) {}
```

is all I get.
Request payload is:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryZVGq8suqFUUSFDtW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="david.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryZVGq8suqFUUSFDtW--
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload)

Comment: The OP is not using jQuery.

Comment: Not duplicate. Writing in js, not jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with your JavaScript method XMLHttpReqest. It takes at least two parameters: Method and url.
Full parameters are:method, url, async, user, password

Change your code from:

```
 http.open("upload.php", data.action);
```

To:

```
 http.open("post", data.action );
```

Update:
   Also remove

```
http.setRequestHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data")
```

Form data already sets its headers for content-type.

Comment: For reference, see [XMLHttpRequest.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open).

Comment: I didn't do that switch on the original code, but still makes no difference in result, unfortunately.

Comment: Try to comment out the setReuestHeader. Give me feedback

Comment: Please, mark the answer as correct. Also updated it.

Comment: Sorry, that did it. I had no idea the browser set the content-type header by itself to the corresponding formdata so that php can receive it.

Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryaOHix0yHdFVLGFaG

And not just:
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Did you checked if memory limit is set to -1 or high enough in php.
Sometime on Apache or iis server, there is also a block on high file uploads.

Comment: Checked. This is small files and the limit's set to 128M.